# Only 1 of two temp tables getting dropped even though the code to drop both is the same

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, temp-tables

I have a block of code that checks of a temp table exists, drops it if it does, then creates the table again filling it with data. This code block is then ran again but for a different table.

When I run the script I get the error

> There is already an object named '#Adjustments' in the database.

even though I have a drop command for it. The script is dropping the first table with no problems so I am not sure why it is not dropping the second table.

```
--Create a temp table with the total Receipts
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Receipts') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Receipts;
END

SELECT  TerminalId,
        ProductId,
        SUM(GrossGallons) AS [GrossGallons],
        SUM(NetGallons) AS [NetGallons]
INTO #Receipts
FROM dbo.ReceiptAdjustment WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE IsReceipt = 1
AND ReceiptAdjustmentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY    TerminalId,
            ProductId,
            ReceiptAdjustmentDate;

--Create a temp table wth the total Adjustments
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempd..#Adjustments') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Adjustments;
END

SELECT  TerminalId,
        ProductId,
        SUM(GrossGallons) AS [GrossGallons],
        SUM(NetGallons) AS [NetGallons]
INTO #Adjustments
FROM dbo.ReceiptAdjustment WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE IsReceipt = 0
AND ReceiptAdjustmentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY    TerminalId,
            ProductId,
            ReceiptAdjustmentDate;
```

Comment: tempd..#Adjustments  "tempdb" is missing the b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo

change

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempd..#Adjustments') IS NOT NULL)
```

with

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Adjustments') IS NOT NULL)
```